# Angular 9 - Open floating component on mouse over of injected HTML

Tags: angular

I have some text that is loaded as a string from the database. This text contains HTML Tags.
Among these are tags like

```
<a href="link-to-somewhere"></a>
```

I place the text on the page with something like:

```
<div [innerHtml]="text"></div>
```

What I want:
 - When the mouse enters: Display a hover container that displays a component that uses the href of the link selector
 - When the mouse leaves: Hide the hover container
 - It's practically the same function wikipedia has to display a preview of an article

I can't use a directive because it doesn't activate if the html is injected like that.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a mouseover event in an outer div and have the second part show

HTML

```
<div (mouseover)="showText()">
<div [innerHtml]="text" *ngIf="displayMe"></div>
</div>
```

Typescript

```
displayMe = false;

showText() {
 displayMe = true;
}
```

Comment: Oh I think I should have asked a clearer question. The text is awlways displayed. When I hover over a link in the text I want an additional hover container to open to display text that is loaded from the links href (kind of like Wikipedia does it).

Comment: Oh you're probably looking for a custom popover. You can look up on Github popover page preview.